# Как и где можно изменить ширину экрана при которой в bootstrap меню сворачивается

Tags: bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка, menu, адаптивность

Для навигации сайта использовал bootsrap. По умолчанию меню сворачивается(появляется гамбургер-меню) при ширине экрана <=750px. Как я могу поменять чтобы гамбургер меню срабатывало при ширине <=1080px? 
Bootstrap я не устанавливал локально, указал просто ссылки(CDN).

Comment: по умолчанию от 767px,  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/700134/13968

Comment: не суть, главное чтобы начинался с 1080px

Comment: Я думаю вам надо произвести настройку bootstrap файлов и скомпилировать их через gulp

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css);

@media screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Static navbar -->
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
              </div>
              <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
```